# In laravel alert not working in view page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I was using alert in a custom registration form for unique email and phone-no but it not working

**not working code**

```
@if ($errors->has('email'))
<span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
<strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
</span>
@endif

@if ($errors->has('phone'))
<span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
<strong>{{ $errors->first('phone') }}</strong>
</span>
@endif
```

when I was used below code it worked but it showing all errors below input area,

**code**

```
 @if($errors->has('email'))
    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
        <li style="color:red">{{ $error }}</li>
    @endforeach 
@endif

  @if($errors->has('phone'))
        @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
            <li style="color:red">{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach 
    @endif
```

Comment: which version of laravel?

Comment: @JagadeshaNH `laravel-5.7` obviously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the bellow example for individual errors display

```
 @if ($errors->any())
   <label for="email" class="error">{{ $errors->first('email') }}</label> 
 @endif

 @if ($errors->any())
       <label for="phone" class="error">{{ $errors->first('phone') }}</label> 
 @endif
```